# How to use updateMany query in PHP with MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, database

In MongoDB 3.2 they have give update multiple documents with one query like below

```
try {
   db.inspectors.updateMany(
      { "inspector" : "J. Clouseau", "Sector" : 4 },
      { $set: { "Patrolling" : false } },
      { upsert: true }
   );
}
catch (e) {
   print(e);
}
```

I've checked php website for MongoDB for this query not having function for this.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoupdatebatch.php

Comment: @pr0metheus, thanks for your answer.Let me check it and update to you

Comment: It works for me although the missing documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Pay attention since there are two versions of mongodb drivers for php. Mongodb 3.2 [requires](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/) the [mongodb.so](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php) driver version, which is different from [mongo.so](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php) (and now deprecated).

Also, as mentionned in the mongodb.so documentation on php.net :

> Application developers should consider using this extension in conjunction with the [MongoDB PHP library](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library) [...]

This official [library](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library) provides the usual mongodb CRUD functions, on top of the new mongodb.so driver, and the [librarie's documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/tutorial/crud/#update-many-documents) also says you can make use `updateMany()` as you would do it in javascript:

```
$updateResult = $collection->updateMany(
    ["inspector" => "J. Clouseau", "Sector" => 4 ],
    ['$set' => ['Patrolling' => false]]
);

printf("Matched %d document(s)\n", $updateResult->getMatchedCount());
printf("Modified %d document(s)\n", $updateResult->getModifiedCount());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [MongoDB_DataObject](https://github.com/viettranme/MongoDB_DataObject/) as example below:

```
$model = new MongoDB_DataObject('inspectors');

$model->Patrolling = false;

$model->whereAdd("inspector = 'J. Clouseau' and Sector = 4");

$model->update();
```

Comment: Please don't just post a link to some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate how it solves the problem in the answer itself.